# google maps controls not visible when overflowing

Tags: google-maps, google-chrome, google-maps-api-3

If I have a google map that's bigger than the container div, and overflow is scroll, then the google logo and zoom + streetview controls won't be visible unless I hover over them. It works fine in Safari and Firefox, it only happens in Chrome. Any suggestions?

Sample jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/jefun0pq/3/

HTML:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js">
</script>

<div id="map-container">
  Only in Chrome: Scroll all the way to the bottom, and you won't be able to see the Google logo and the zoom + street view controls. Hover in the bottom right of the map, and the logo and controls will become visible. 
  <div id="map">

  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 12,
  center: {lat: -28.643387, lng: 153.612224}}
);
```

CSS:

```
#map-container {
  width: 100%;
  height:300px;
  padding-left:40px;
  overflow:scroll;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#map {
  height: 500px;
  width:100%;
}
```

Comment: It works for me with Chrome 52.0.2743.116. What's your Chrome version and OS?

Comment: I have the same Version 52.0.2743.116 (64-bit) on osx 10.11.5 (15F34)